# Setting the value of a HiddenField contained in the Master page from a child page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio, bootstrap-4

I have a master page that contains the following section:

```
<section id="content">
                <asp:HiddenField ID="MasterHidden" runat="server" />
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Content" runat="server" />
</section>
```

This master page has two child pages. In one of the child pages is a GridView that contains an image button:

```
<dx:BootstrapGridViewDataColumn Caption="Requirements" FieldName="Requirements" VisibleIndex="5">
      <DataItemTemplate>
              <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="RequirementsBtn" OnClientClick="setMasterFieldValue()"/>
      </DataItemTemplate>
</dx:BootstrapGridViewDataColumn>
```

When the image button is clicked, I want to run a javascript function that will set the hidden field value in the master page like this:

```
function setMasterFieldValue(){
    document.getElementById('<%=MasterHidden.ClientID %>').value = "TestValue";
}
```

I have not been able to get the child page to "talk" to the master page. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Your setMasterFieldValue() function is located on a content page, so

```
MasterHidden.ClientID
```

has no meaning on the content page. In order to access controls on the master page from a content page you must do it through the content page's naming container. Please see the following link for sample code on how to do this.
[Example from MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/xxwa0ff0(v=vs.100))